# Origin should match a registered origin URL. Origin URLs can be registered on the Account Kit developer page

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, account-kit

I want to integrate facebook AccounKit in my website. I refer [this](https://github.com/auth0-blog/blog-passwordless-authentication.git).
I am getting "**Origin should match a registered origin URL. Origin URLs can be registered on the Account Kit developer page.**" error in debug mode. What is the solution for this? I have added domain URLs in Account setting page as well as AccountKit Setting also.

Attached Images for reference.

1.[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfYQG.png)  2. [App Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7sf8.png)
 3. [AccountKit Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA7xt.png)

1) **Server.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const Guid = require('guid');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const Mustache  = require('mustache');
const Request  = require('request');
const Querystring  = require('querystring');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
  
var csrf_guid = Guid.raw();
const api_version = "v1.0";
const app_id = "**************";
const app_secret = '*************************';
const me_endpoint_base_url = 'https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.0/me';
const token_exchange_base_url = 'https://graph.accountkit.com/v1.0/access_token'; 

function loadLogin() {
  return fs.readFileSync('dist/login.html').toString();
}

app.get('/', function(request, response){
  var view = {
    appId: app_id,
    csrf: csrf_guid,
    version: api_version,
  };

  var html = Mustache.to_html(loadLogin(), view);
  response.send(html);
});

function loadLoginSuccess() {
  return fs.readFileSync('dist/login_success.html').toString();
}

app.post('/sendcode', function(request, response){
  // CSRF check
  if (request.body.csrf_nonce === csrf_guid) {
    var app_access_token = ['AA', app_id, app_secret].join('|');
    var params = {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: request.body.code,
      access_token: app_access_token
      appsecret_proof: app_secret
    };
  
    // exchange tokens
    var token_exchange_url = token_exchange_base_url + '?' + Querystring.stringify(params);
    Request.get({url: token_exchange_url, json: true}, function(err, resp, respBody) {
      console.log(respBody);
      var view = {
        user_access_token: respBody.access_token,
        expires_at: respBody.expires_at,
        user_id: respBody.id, 
      };
      // get account details at /me endpoint
      var me_endpoint_url = me_endpoint_base_url + '?access_token=' + respBody.access_token;
      Request.get({url: me_endpoint_url, json:true }, function(err, resp, respBody) {
        // send login_success.html
        console.log(respBody);
        if (respBody.phone) {
          view.method = "SMS"
          view.identity = respBody.phone.number;
        } else if (respBody.email) {
          view.method = "Email"
          view.identity = respBody.email.address;
        }
        var html = Mustache.to_html(loadLoginSuccess(), view);
        response.send(html);
      });
    });
  } 
  else {
    // login failed
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.end("Something went wrong. :( ");
  }
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

2) **Login.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Password Free: Facebook Account Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <style>
   body {
    text-align: center;
    background: #EEE;
   }
   .mdl-button {
    width: 100%;
   }
  </style>
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-offset">
     <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
     <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
     <h1 class="mdl-typography--title">Passwordless Authentication</h1>
     <h2 class="mdl-typography--subhead">Facebook Account Kit</h2>
     <p><strong>Login via:</strong></p>
     <ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list">
     <li class="mdl-list__item">
       <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
         <button onclick="loginWithSMS();" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-typography--text-center">SMS</button>
       </span>
     </li>
     <li class="mdl-list__item">
       <button onclick="loginWithEmail();" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent mdl-typography--text-center"> Email</button>
     </li>
   </ul>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form id="my_form" name="my_form" action="/sendcode" method="POST" style="display: none;">
   <input type="text" id="code" name="code">
   <input type="text" id="csrf_nonce" name="csrf_nonce">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

  <script>
    // initialize Account Kit with CSRF protection
    AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
     console.log("{{abcd}}")
      AccountKit.init(
        {
          appId:*****************, 
          state:"{{abcd}}", 
          version:"v1.0",
    debug:true
        }
      );
    };

    // login callback
    function loginCallback(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
        document.getElementById("code").value = response.code;
        document.getElementById("csrf_nonce").value = response.state;
        document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
      }
      else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {
        // handle authentication failure
      }
      else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {
        // handle bad parameters
      }
    }

    function loginWithSMS(){
     AccountKit.login("PHONE",{}, loginCallback);
    }

    function loginWithEmail(){
     AccountKit.login("EMAIL", {}, loginCallback);
    }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

3)Login-Success.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AccountKitJS App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <style>
   body {
    text-align: center;
    background: #EEE;
   }
   .mdl-button {
    width: 100%;
   }
  </style>
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mdl-grid">
   <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-offset">
    <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
    <h1 class="mdl-typography--title">Passwordless Authentication</h1>
    <h2 class="mdl-typography--subhead">You're In!</h2>
    <p><strong>Details:</strong></p>
     <ul class="demo-list-icon mdl-list">
     <li class="mdl-list__item">
       <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
         <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-icon">fingerprint</i>
         <span id="token">{{method}}</span>
       </span>
     </li>
     <li class="mdl-list__item">
       <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
         <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-icon">face</i>
         <span id="nickname">{{identity}}</span>
       </span>
     </li>
     <li class="mdl-list__item">
       <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
         <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-icon">person</i>
         <span id="user_id">{{user_id}}</span>
       </span>
     </li>
     <li class="mdl-list__item">
       <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
         <button onclick="goToLogin()" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored mdl-typography--text-center">Try Another</button>
       </span>
     </li>
   </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <script>
      function goToLogin(){
     window.location.href = "/";
   }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got help from Facebook support, I missed some parameters in init function.

```
AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
        AccountKit.init(
          {
            appId:*****************, 
            state:"abcd", 
            version:"v1.0",
            debug:true,
            redirect:"//RedirectURl"
          }
        );
      };
```

Note: Redirect URL and Origin URL must Be Specified in Account Kit Settings.
Refer images Below.
1)[Account Kit Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di0ir.png)

2)[App Settings>>Advance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ot9p.png)